# Связать 2 формы C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо связать 2 формы, чтобы во вторую форму передать данные с первой. Написал код для первой формы:

```
SolutionPage S = new SolutionPage();
S.Owner = this;
S.ShowDialog();
```

И для второй:

```
Window1 W = this.Owner as Window1;
```

Но данные получить не могу ибо `W==null`. Как это исправить?

Comment: а ты уверен что this.Owner имеет Window1? Под дебагом что пишет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делайте так.

Нужные данные кладите во ViewModel для первой формы (обычно через Binding), ViewModel подключайте через DataContext.

Во второй форме нужные данные берите из её ViewModel'и.

Данные между разными VM перебрасывайте в бизнес-логике.

(И выучите MVVM, разумеется.)

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так:
    Window1 W = (Window1)this.Owner;
Для меня работало

Comment: тоже пробовал, но W==null, соответственно при обращении к данным этой формы вылетает исключение

Comment: Странно. А можно больше кода... контекст не понятен.